# How to redeploy JS file without redeploying whole application

Tags: javascript, java, weblogic, web-deployment

I am developing very large application and now I am working on some small changes in js files, but in order to see them I need to redeploy whole application for almost 30mins, I would like to know if it possible to get js changes withou redeploying.
I strongly believe that it is possible but I don't know how.
Server WebLogic 12.2.1.3

Comment: find where it is deployed and change the file directly?

Comment: I am unable to find js files in directory with deployed war. There are just compiled classes

Comment: unfortunately I don't know how web logic deploys things